# Difference between Integer and int in Java

Tags: integer, int

What is the difference between int and Integer in Java ? I know that "Integer" is a class and "int" is a datatype but they both work the same. Can they be used interchangeably ?

Answer (score 1):

An `int` is a 32 bit integer that is represented internally as a 4 byte primitive. An `Integer` is a Java object that represents an `int` value. `Integer` instances are needed when working with the Collections API, as the collections only work with objects and not primitives. `Integer` also contains a bunch of useful methods that make working with them somewhat easier. The downside of using `Integer` is that it uses roughly 4 times the memory of the primitive version.